# jQuery remove() on element doesn't hide used space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm removing an element using `remove()` (it's a `<li>` with `display: inline;` set, although the same problem seems to exist with `display: block;`), and while the element is removed from the page the space it was occupying isn't.

Is this standard behaviour and so should I be using another method instead? The `<li>` contains a form field, so I'm wanting to ideally not have this form field sent through to the server - hence using `remove()` instead of `hide()`.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Is this behavior occurs in all browsers or in one specific?

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem on http://www.jsbin.com/ and then share it with us, that would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a bare-bones example, so I'm trying to figure out what in the existing code is causing it. It's not a jQuery issue. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are experiencing is not standard behavior. When removing element from DOM, occupied space should be also removed

Answer (score 2):

This could be one of the reason. There could be break tags after the element. You might be hiding/removing only the element, but the break tags still remain which cause empty space.

Ex:

```
<div id="one">Blah Blah</div>
<br/>
<div id="two">Blah Blah</div>
<br/>
<div id="three">Blah Blah</div>
<br/>
<div id="four">Blah Blah</div>
```

If you hide/remove div id "three", There will be 3 unnecessary break tags.

Imagine a long such list which is generated with your code and your hiding 20 elements, then there will be 20 break tags which create empty blocks.

To overcome this, add a class to all these divs and give style attribute 'padding'