# jquery remove doesnt hide used space in ie6 and ie7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

Couldn't comment on this post, which states the problem I'm experiencing:

[jQuery remove() on element doesn't hide used space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588671/jquery-remove-on-element-doesnt-hide-used-space)

I can reproduce this in IE7 (and a colleague in IE6), my link is here:

http://www.pritaeas.net/tools/linkfarm/

If you select a tag the list gets filtered and the tag added to the selected div. Unselecting it will reset the taglist, and remove() the tag from the selected div. Selecting another one will result in positioning the new tag next to the element that has been removed.

Is this a jQuery issue, or can this be fixed by changing my css.

T.i.a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer thinks the <li> tag is still there.

I've used [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), which shows the "IE interpreted Source Code" as:

```
<H2>Selected tags</H2>
<UL class=selected sizcache="279" sizset="0">
<LI sizcache="35" sizset="0"> </LI>
<LI sizcache="65" sizset="0"> </LI>
<LI sizcache="177" sizset="0"> </LI>
<LI sizcache="278" sizset="0"><INPUT class=analytics id=filterIDanalytics type=checkbox CHECKED value=analytics> <LABEL>analytics</LABEL></LI></UL>
```

I'm not sure as to the best way to remove the <li> tags, but perhaps try using the jQuery hide() method.

Sometimes even using the jQuery hide() method doesn't work in IE, in which case sometimes specifying hide("fast") will do the trick.

Comment: I've tried both hide() and hide("fast") (locally) but the problem persist. Any more ideas ?

Comment: Fixed logic, .remove did not recognize the parent correctly. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help, sorry for the late response I haven't logged in for a week!

Comment: anytime you see: sizcache="35" sizset="0" it is symptomatic of a javascript error in your code somewhere - kills the sizzle part of jQuery cleanup.